# Show filtered result from api in React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that fetches data and then I am setting that data via state. If I want to filter that data based on certain criteria or fields from the api, would I do the filter method? or is this not advisable for state objects?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x7tlxr?file=src/App.js

So far I am doing this: but it's not working as the filtering does not happen.

```
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<any>([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
const [isError, setIsError] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

const url: string = 'https://xxxxxx';

useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    const loadData = async (): Promise<any> => {
        try {
            const response = await axios(url);
            if (mounted) {
                setFetchData(response.data);
                setLoading(false);
                setIsError(false);
                console.log('data mounted')
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setIsError(true)
            setLoading(false);
            setFetchData([]);
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    loadData();
    return () => {
        mounted = false;
        console.log('cleaned');
    };
},
    [url]
);
```

function to filter based on `onClick`:

```
onClick={(idx: number) => {
    const resultInnerNew = fetchData.filter((statusPoint: any) => statusPoint.status === 'New');
    setFetchData(resultInnerNew)
}
```

**binding to template:**

```
   {isError ? <p className="mt-5">There is an error fetching the data!</p> : <div className="container"></div>}
   {loading ? <div>Loading ...</div> : <div className="cards row card-container mt-5">
   // data here
   </div>
   }
```

Comment: ... `const resultInnerNew` - is a function (isn't it) ... `setFetchData(resultInnerNew)}` - You are setting the function to the state (slice `fetchData`) or what ...?

Comment: So I am setting the state to the filtered value

Comment: But its not working if I log to console, the array gets sliced everytime

Comment: Ok, so thats wrong I guess need to show the filtered result, what would be the best way?

Comment: Where is the `onClick` handler used exactly?

Comment: Also, `resultInnerNew` is not a function, it is indeed the result of the filtering. Not sure what @Vovan_Super is talking about. You just need to assign the `onClick` handler properly and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an arrow function to update the state and filter the data as below,

```
onClick={(idx: number) => {
    setFetchData(data => data.filter(statusPoint => statusPoint.status === 'New')
}}
```

A quick review on `Array.prototype.filter()`, this code will only keep the values which have `statusPoint.status` equal to 'New' in your array.

Comment: that does not work, what does data correspond to, in relation to my code above?

Comment: data corresponds to the current state.

Comment: Here is a code snippet referring to my answer,
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-ypgko?file=/Hello.js